# Ambiguous modifiers

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about ambiguous modifiers.  In this [Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2017/05/oops) article:

> Even the fact of the meeting between the president and, respectively, Sergei Lavrov and Sergey Kislyak, had previously looked bad for Mr Trump. It took place the day after he sacked Mr Comey at least partly, Mr Trump himself suggested, because he disapproved of *an FBI counter-espionage investigation* into *Russia’s effort* to rig the election last year, ***with alleged assistance from one or two of the president’s then associates***.

Based on semantics, the modifier "*with alleged assistance from one or two of the president’s then associates*" probably modifies "*Russia’s effort*", not "*an FBI counter-espionage investigation*".  But to readers not informed about the current affairs, would the modifier "*with alleged assistance from one or two of the president’s then associates*" be ambiguous?

Comment: You example shouldn't be "ambiguous" to someone who has no idea whether that "alleged assistance" was provided to Russia or the FBI (or indeed, to Trump himself), because the "rule" (such as it is) is that working *backwards* from the adverbial ***with-*** clause, you assign it to the first *credible* noun phrase (i.e. - the *most recent one*, which should be right at the top of the "memory stack" in the reader's mind). That's to say, in this specific example any potential ambiguity is negligible, since the default parsing approach gives the "correct" meaning anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  So, the sentence "*She saw the dog* ***in the garden***" is not ambiguous?

Comment: Like I said, the *default* is to assign the adverbial clause to the nearest credible preceding NP. Unless context dictated/strongly suggested otherwise, it would be perverse to interpret your example as meaning *[when she was in the garden] she saw the dog [which was outside the garden]*. Obviously the issue of "credibility" doesn't arise there, but it would with, say, *She saw the dog **using binoculars***. (And if you want to see ambiguity in *that* sentence, I don't think I can help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

*"...the president's **then** associates"* establishes the time reference of the modifying phrase, which connects it to *"Russia's effort ... **last year**".*

Moreover, this doesn't work:

> [Trump] disapproved of an FBI counter-espionage investigation ... with alleged assistance from one or two of the president’s then associates.

Nor does this:

> The neighbors disapproved of the loud partying ... with alleged
>   assistance from the teenager's parents.

Comment: So, the sentence "*She saw the dog* ***in the garden***" is not ambiguous?